# Setting htdocs folder in Dropbox folder - Access Forbidden - Linux

Tags: linux, xampp, dropbox, htdocs

i use Linux and i did the following procedures to move htdocs files in Dropbox :

1. `mkdir ~/Dropbox/www/`
2. `ln -s ~/Dropbox/www/ /opt/lampp/htdocs/`

and when i try to access this folder i get

> **Access forbidden!**
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the
>   server.
>
> If you think this is a server error,
>   please contact the webmaster.
>
> **Error 403**
>
> localhost Fri May 13 17:32:37 2011
>   Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/1.0.0c
>   PHP/5.3.5 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1
>   mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/www/ /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

A normal user won't have access to the `/opt` directory (unless you `chown`'d it). Try doing the same thing with `sudo`.

```
sudo ln -s ~/Dropbox/www/ /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```